# How to save and retrieve latitude and longitude from a point in Symfony2 and Doctrine2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, geolocation, doctrine

I have a Symfony2/Doctrine application that has the need to store and retrieve latitude/longitude values.

I've found plenty of bundles that handle geolocation, but it appears most people's needs are different than my own and I can't seem to solve this simple problem...

All I need to do at the moment is save latitude and longitude properties of an entity to a Point column, and when the entity is loaded, load latitude and longitude from that point.

I've followed http://codeutopia.net/blog/2011/02/19/using-spatial-data-in-doctrine-2/ and i have a "location" property on my entity that maps to a Point column. This is great. But I don't quite see how to set that point from lat/long, or how to retrieve lat/long from that point, without doing a custom DQL any time i need to load/save the entity.

In a non-symfony/doctrine application I would do something like: `"SELECT *, X(location) as latitude, Y(location) as longitude FROM...` to load the latitude and longitude, but with SF2 and doctrine I can't seem to figure out what I need to do.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: The http://codeutopia.net/blog/2011/02/19/using-spatial-data-in-doctrine-2/ is a broken link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Considering that your entity has a field of the "point" type you linked, manipulating your coordinates would be as simple as in these three examples :

```
/* Returns the latitude of your existing entity */
$entity->getPoint()->getLatitude();

/* Creates a new point of coordinates (42,42) and sets it as your entity's coordinates */
$point = new Point(42, 42);
$entity->setPoint($point);

/* Adds 1 to your existing entity's latitude */
$tmp = $entity->getPoint();
$tmp->setLatitude($tmp->getLatitude() + 1);
$entity->setPoint($tmp);
```

Comment: Thank you! Super simple, I knew I was just missing something basic here